# eOS on chromebook booting to black screen

Tags: release-juno, greeter, chromebook

I have recently installed elementary on my Acer Chromebook 11, but now whenever i boot it up it, it goes through the boot menu, it just goes to a black screen (the screen is turned on just displaying black). 
It works completely fine with other distros, and i suspect it might be an issue with the Chromebook's graphics and the LightDM greeter pantheon uses.